# Draw String using reversed X and Y

Tags: blackberry, graphics, java-me

I want to draw a String while specifying beginning X and Y. For that purpose I use `graphics.drawText(String, X, Y).`

The problem is that the application supports arabic too. When the user changes to arabic, I want to draw the text beginning from an X and Y and go the other way.

**English:  ->**

**Arabic:   <-**

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Java ME / Java on Blackberry, but in regular Java you could determine the length of the string in pixels with [FontMetrics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html)  .
Then, you would use

```
graphics.drawText(String,X-length,Y)
```

The order of the text in Arabic remains the responsibility of the one who created the Arabic version of the string.

I hope this is applicable for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the maximum pixel width of the text with a different version of [Graphics](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html).drawText:
`drawText(String aText, int aX, int aY, int aFlags, int aWidth)`

This way you can specify the right side of the area to start drawing right-to-left text.

Comment: "this did not work" -- could you explain that more?  What actually happened?